# How To Save A Matrix In Flash Memory In STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c

i'm new in stm32 and in embedded world in general. I'm using a nucleo64 f446re and I want to save a matrix in the flash memory.
Can I use CONST to do this?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad that's not true at all. You're confusing something.

Comment: Did you read the stm32 reference manual to see what they write about flash?

Comment: @po.pe Why would MCU reference manual have any info where to locate data by using C language const qualifier?

Comment: STM32. when writing to flash, you need to unlock, zero, write, lock just as much. it's flash memory, you can't just address and write to it like RAM, as that's physically not how flash works, @TirdadSadriNejad.

Comment: @MarcusMüller actually the writing part is the same as you mentioned. it's the reading that makes the difference. in the AVRs we had to use progmem directives even for reading things because otherwise the compiler would copy [even a const] the variable in the ram, then use it (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, declaring your array as const in C language will leave the data in program flash memory area and access it there on STM32 MCUs.

Comment: That *does* depend on linker scripts, though.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes we both know it does - but in the case for the OP making first C program ever, that would be the default case. Just out of curiosity, where else than internal flash area it would make sense to place const-declared items on an STM32 platform? To an external memory-mapped flash chip? On an AVR, the const items are stored in flash, but since flash is not directly readable even the standard const items are copied into SRAM by startup code and thus must fit into SRAM, and data really stored in flash is used via special functions that can access it using LPM instruction.

Comment: Well, "where does it make sense" might be an algorithmic question ("Let me just process this static piece of data where some values are filled in from ADC observations" should be contiguous in RAM), but generally I'd agree with you – flash can't be prefetched concurrently with RAM, if I remember STM32F4 correctly, so you gain nothing in bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

*Every* part of your program code is stored in flash on that microcontroller – that's the only programmable memory it has.

It's up to your compiler and linker to either leave data that you don't modify if flash and read it at runtime directly from there when you use it, or to load it into RAM first and use it from there – if you modify that data structure at runtime, you will have to have it in RAM, so non-constant things always get loaded from flash into RAM (in fact, the compiler adds code that does that loading at an appropriate time "behind the scenes").

If you want some changed data to persist after a power-off, you'll have to indeed write it to flash. That requires a specific routine of system functions that you use (unlocking a flash page, erasing it, writing it, locking it again).

If you just need some constant matrix, that's in flash, anyway, and adding `const` will not change its storage position per se – the question is whether it gets loaded from flash to RAM first or gets directly used. Unless your matrix is too large for RAM, I'd recommend, however, just letting the compiler and linker scripts do that decision for you – flash and RAM typically have different access times.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you need 3 things to place a variable in flash:

- Declare the variable as `const`.
- Declare the variable with *static storage duration*. That is, either at file scope and/or with `static` keyword.
- A "flash build" linker script in your IDE. It is common that embedded systems IDEs use a so-called "RAM build" during debugging, where everything gets loaded to RAM instead of flash, for the purpose of faster programming. This is mostly an obsolete remain from back in the EPROM days. It should be avoided on modern MCUs - always load the code to flash.

Comment: Yep. If you don't declare as static the MCU will try and load it from flash memory to RAM and run it there and if it is really big it won't compile because not enough RAM.